# Doing T Test in C#

Tags: c#, statistics

I'm trying to run a T Test on some data. It seems that using the Statistic Formula class is a good way of doing this. But I can't seem to get it to work. Here is my code.

```
Chart Chart1 = new Chart();
        Collection<string> series1 = new Collection<string>();
        series1.Add("5");
        series1.Add("7");
        series1.Add("9");
        Collection<string> series2 = new Collection<string>();
        series2.Add("1");
        series2.Add("3");
        series2.Add("2");


        TTestResult result = Chart1.DataManipulator.Statistics.TTestPaired(0.2, 0.05, "series1" , "series2");
```

I keep getting the exception:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Web.DataVisualization.dll

Additional information: Formula Data Object - Input Series does not exist in Series collection: series1

Can someone point me in the right direction. What am I doing wrong here? If there is an easier way I am up for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you need to add both series to the chart, then add the data to the series. Otherwise, the chart has no way of conducting the test since it doesn't know about the string collections you've defined.

Try this:

```
Chart chart1 = new Chart();

chart1.Series.Add("series1");
chart1.Series["series1"].Points.AddY(5);
chart1.Series["series1"].Points.AddY(7);
chart1.Series["series1"].Points.AddY(9);

chart1.Series.Add("series2");
chart1.Series["series2"].Points.AddY(1);
chart1.Series["series2"].Points.AddY(3);
chart1.Series["series2"].Points.AddY(2);

TTestResult result = chart1.DataManipulator.Statistics.TTestPaired(0.2, 0.05, "series1", "series2");
```

Comment: Thanks! So what do you mean by your comment at the end?

Comment: Sorry, I was just misunderstanding statistics. Please ignore. It's been a few years since I took it in school.